# How to remove all expired cookie from CookieCollection?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

How to remove all expired cookie from a CookieCollection ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var cookies = Request.Cookies;
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookies)
{
    if (cookie.Expires < DateTime.Now)
    {
        Request.Cookies.Remove(cookie.Name);
    }
}
```

Please note the [excerpt from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx),

> Calling the Remove method of the Cookies collection removes the cookie
>   from the collection on the server side, so the cookie will not be sent
>   to the client. However, the method does not remove the cookie from the
>   client if it already exists there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date. The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it.

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);//add -1 days
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you remove a cookie is to change it expire date to some thing that has already passed.. **but a expired cookie should never be sent from the browser in the first case...**